# Exclude inlined modules

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am inlining a `splash.css` and a `splash.js` file into the `index.html` using `style-ext-html-webpack-plugin` and `script-ext-html-webpack-plugin`.

The [service worker](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) goes through the assets it runs into the mentioned files trying to cache them, but fails with:

> http://localhost:8080/splash.a72065b4ca5e25fbaed5.js?__uncache=3%2F20%2F2017%2C%208%3A36%3A01%20PM Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:8080/splash.css?__uncache=3%2F20%2F2017%2C%208%3A36%3A01%20PM Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I'm surprised because the inlined files should be forgotten after they are inlined, no?

How to JUST inline those files and not emit them into the output?